# How do you animate changes to a stream from firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream, jquery-animate

I have a streambuilder that creates a snapshot of a firestore instance. The data is a list of names with a counter of upvotes associate with each name. Whenever someone upvotes a name I would like there to be an animation when the numbers change. Also if a name is added to the list I would like to add an animation for the added name when it is inserted into the widget tree.

Currently whenever there is a change in the background data the entire widget is rebuilt with no animation--seems like this is just how streambuilder works.  I would like to animate any changes instead.

Comment: The word animation is vague. Unless you have in mind a specific animation, it is difficult to help.

Comment: When a new name is added it would do something like slide in from the bottom. If the counter of upvotes changes it would do something like jump up and down for a few seconds.